# Gnome 3 - Strange black areas inside windows

Tags: gnome, ati

I'm facing a strange issue after upgrading from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 (well, technically, it wasn't an upgrade, as the network upgrade failed and I had to do a clean install). On many application windows, there are black areas, sometimes taking up the entire background of the window, sometimes only portions of it. This issue occurs on all GTK+ and Window themes.

I'm using GNOME 3.12.2, running on an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4570 graphics card.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: I've been having the same issue. Have you had any luck?

Comment: @danielu13: It got resolved automatically when I tried to install `ubuntu-session` (unsuccessfully, of course. Apparently, Gnome 3.12 and ubuntu-session cannot co-exist due to a dependency that requires a gnome package less than version 3.10). It said I had to install some dependencies before that, and those dependencies contained quite a few `gnome-*` packages (unfortunately, I didn't note their names). I suppose those packages failed to install during my Network Upgrade. Maybe you could try the same?

Answer (score 8):

Try running this in a terminal:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal
```

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaanks